# C dynamically allocated array not being passed properly

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, malloc, 2d

I have one function such as

```
currentCompressedLetter = malloc(extractHeight * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < extractHeight; i++)
  currentCompressedLetter[i] = malloc(extractWidth * sizeof(int));
```

where it sets the values to a global array `int **currentCompressedLetter`

When I try to print the output to screen using a separate function, and I pass the `currentCompressedLetter` as a parameter, it gives wrong output.

```
void print(int height, int width, int sq[height][width])
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(i < height)
  {
    while(j< width)
    {
     if (sq[i][j] == 1)
        printf(".");
     else if (sq[i][j] == 2)
        printf("=");
     else printf("'");
     j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
    j = 0;
   }
}
```

But if I copy the print statement into my first function, it works properly. So the issue is with it not being sent properly or somtehing to the global variable once it leaves that function. How can I amend this

Comment: Show where you're calling `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function expects an array of VLAs, however your `currentCompressedLetter` points to an array of pointers.

I assume you wish to use `print` to print `currentCompressedLetter`. However, this is not possible, as a VLA is not a pointer (nor is a fixed-length array for that matter). If you tried this, you would get a compiler message. You shouldn't ignore compiler messages even if they appear to be "only" warnings.

The simplest fix would be to change `print` to:

```
void print(int height, int width, int **sq)
```

and leave the contents of it the same. If you also want to print VLAs then have two separate functions.

Comment: It worked. I feel incredibly stupid right now. I thought that would give me a seg fault so I didn't bother trying it.

How does the C compiler know to not go out of range with this function.

Comment: It doesn't. It's up to you to pass `height` and `width` that correctly describe how many entries you've allocated and filled in in `sq`.